# In Kurosawa's Yojimbo why did Master Homma run away?

Tags: plot-explanation, yojimbo

Seibei hires Sanjuro (the protagonist) to be his bodyguard and to lead the fight against the other group. Seibei agreed to pay Sanjuro 50 ryo (25 up front); the master Homma complains that he was paid only 2 ryo.

Why did Homma run away? Was it the pay or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Without any backstory, the only reasonable conclusion is that

**Master Homma is a coward, and now that the Ronin is here to fight, Homma knows he won't be missed**